# Unable to find template with BluePrints Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to take a modular approach to designing my Flask App.

So each module as multiple routes. See below

[image]

Templates folder

[image]

Contents of my home_routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, session, abort
from flask import render_template


def home_blueprints(app):
    home_routes = Blueprint("home_routes", __name__, template_folder='../../templates', static_folder='../../static')

    @home_routes.route('/home/Links')
    def links():
        return render_template('links.html')

    @home_routes.route('/home/Confirmation')
    def confirmation():
        return render_template('Confirmation.html')

    @home_routes.route('/')
    def main():
        return render_template('main.html')

    @home_routes.route('/home/Contactus', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def contact():
        if request.method == "POST":
            token = session.pop('_csrf_token', None)
            if not token or token != request.form.get('_csrf_token'):
                abort(403)
        return render_template('GoogleForm.html')


    app.register_blueprint(home_routes)
```

Contents of believe_routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import render_template


def believe_blueprints(app):
    believe_routes = Blueprint("believe_routes", __name__, template_folder='../../templates', static_folder='../../static')

    @believe_routes.route('/home/Believe/Truth_About_God')
    def truth_about_God():
        return render_template('The_Truth_Concerning_God.html')

    @believe_routes.route('/home/Believe/Truth_We_Believe')
    def the_truth_we_beleive():
        return render_template('The_Truth_We_Believe.html')

    @believe_routes.route('/home/Believe/Truth_About_Christ')
    def truth_about_christ():
        return render_template('The_Truth_About_Christ.html')

    @believe_routes.route('/home/Believe/Truth_About_Church')
    def truth_about_church():
        return render_template('The_Truth_About_Church.html')

    @believe_routes.route('/home/Believe/Truth_About_Salvation')
    def truth_about_salvation():
        return render_template('The_Truth_About_Salvation.html')

    @believe_routes.route('/Believe')
    def truth_we_believe():
        return render_template('Truth_We_Believe.html')

    app.register_blueprint(believe_routes)
```

Contents of **init**.py

```
from home_routes import home_blueprints
from believe_routes import believe_blueprints

def configure_blueprints(app):
    home_blueprints(app)
    believe_blueprints(app)
```

Only the home_routes work. The URLs in the believe_routes do not work. I get a 404

```
INFO     2017-05-26 18:01:44,325 module.py:813] default: "GET /home/Believe/Truth_About_Christ HTTP/1.1" 404 233
```

I am calling configure_blueprints(app) from create_app which is then called from main.py.

Any thoughts please.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your templates folder?

Comment: Screenshot of templates folder has been added.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the exact setup working in my end. I can't figure out what causing this error in your end.

Answer (score 0):

the 404 is not for the template reason, maybe you can try this code to view whether blueprint is registed to flask instance, and you can put your output back for more details...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
from flask import Flask

from home_routes import home_blueprints
from believe_routes import believe_blueprints


app = Flask('demo')


def configure_blueprints(app):
    home_blueprints(app)
    believe_blueprints(app)

configure_blueprints(app)
print(app.url_map)
```

i hope this would help you ..

Comment: I see the following in url_map

Comment: Map([ home_routes.confirmation>, home_routes.contact>, home_routes.links>, home_routes.map>, admin.admin_landing>, home_routes.main>, ' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> static>, ' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> home_routes.static>, ' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> admin.static>])

Comment: `believe_blueprints` is not registered to Flask, maybe there were some thing wrong in codes, can you paste all the code for calling `configure_blueprints`? @VinayJoseph